# Grouping by month with series of epoch timestamps in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a list of epoch timestamps that I would like to graph using chart.js.

```
[1432317109519, 1432318109519, 1432319109519, ...]
```

Grouping as data to give to chart.js, ie each time is one unit on Y axis:

```
[{
  x: 1432317109519,
  y: 1
},{
  x: 1432318109519,
  y: 1
},{
  x: 1432319109519,
  y: 1
}]
```

I am trying to have chart.js round to the nearest month for each timestamp:

```
  chartOptions = {
    type: 'line',
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit:  'month',
          round: 'month'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When doing this all my y-axis are 1.  I am trying to get a sum of all values over a period of a month.  Am I misinterpreting what the 'round' property does?

[image]

Comment: Are you using v3 or v2?

Comment: "ng2-charts": "3.0.0-rc.5", which uses "chart.js": "3.5.1",

Answer (score 0):

In v3 you need a date adapter and scales have been changed, for all changes please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: 1632664467243,
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: 1611664467243,
        y: 10
      }],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month',
          round: 'month'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('tt').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<canvas id="tt"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

From the moment adapter [readme](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-moment#readme):

```sh
npm install moment chartjs-adapter-moment --save
```

```js
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';

new Chart()
```

Comment: Using angular, "ng2-charts", not really sure where/how to add the moment adapter.  Digging into chart.js docs, adding adapter isn't very clear either.  Says one needs to be present, not really sure what "present" means.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: It does give feedback if no date adapter is found, are you sure you changed your scale correctly? like in myt example so to an object instead of a array

Comment: Yup I missed something in the scale config.  It is throwing the error mentioned in my latest update.

Comment: Never realy worked with the moment adapter, only with the date-fns adapter, with date-fns it works fine giving the epoch, since its an moment error it seems like the adapter itself is loaded fine but moment doesnt like the input you are giving it

Comment: Tried with ISO8601 string as well, same issue.  I will dig into the adapter to see if I can determine what is going on.  Maybe I still have something wrong with my data format or options.

Comment: Ok, my data format was messed up.  I am seeing data, however each entry on the y axis is one.  I must be misunderstanding what the 'round' property does.  If I have multiple entires with a value of 1 over a month, will round on month group those together with the sum?  Which is really my original question, sans the errors in config I had